# compare and replace column value in excel vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to compare "Master" worksheet with "New" worksheet based on first column value. If same is available in "New" worksheet, then I want to compare column "E" of matched row of "Master" worksheet with column "E" of matched row of "New" worksheet. If there is any diffenrence in value then replace column value "E" of "master" by column value "E" of "New" and highlight entire row by color.

```
Sub CompareValues()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range, c As Range
Set sh1 = Sheets("New")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Master")
lr = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Get last row with data in Column A on Sheet 1.
Set rng = sh2.Range("A2:A" & lr) 'Set compare range to a variable
For Each c In rng 'Make cell by cell comparison
    If Application.CountIf(sh1.Range("A:A"), c.Value) <> 0 Then
        If c.EntireRow.Range("E") <> sh1.Range("E", c.Value) Then
           ' to fill the value into another sheet simply replace from sh1 to c.Range                
            c.Range("E" & i).Copy (sh1.Range("E" & i))
            Range(c, sh2.Cells(c.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your solution to fit my requirement. Thanks for your help.

```
Sub UpdateSheet()
Dim masterSheet As Excel.Worksheet, newSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim e, n, masterCell As Excel.Range, newCell As Excel.Range
Dim columnOffset As Integer

Const idColumn = 1 'column A has index 1
Const newDataColumn = 5 'column E has index 5
columnOffset = newDataColumn - idColumn 'offset between those columns is 4

Set masterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New")

'iterate over all cells of the first column in the used range of this worksheet
For Each e In masterSheet.UsedRange.Columns(idColumn).Cells
    Set masterCell = e
    If masterCell.Value <> Empty Then
        For Each n In newSheet.UsedRange.Columns(idColumn).Cells
            Set newCell = n

            'if the cell on the master sheet is not empty and the values of both cells match
            If masterCell.Value = newCell.Value Then
                'select cells in column "E"
                Set masterCell = masterCell.Offset(0, columnOffset)
                Set newCell = newCell.Offset(0, columnOffset)

                'copy values and paint row if values don't match
                If masterCell.Value <> newCell.Value Then
                    masterCell.Value = newCell.Value
                    masterCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                End If
            End If
        Next n
    End If
Next e

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment on this question (or post pictures)...

To clarify (*assuming my third column would be column 'E'*):

If sheet "Master" looks like this:

```
| first | info | d'oh  |  
| two   | info |  4    |
| three | info | hello |
```

and "New" looks like that:

```
| first | info | d'oh  |  
| two   | blub |  5    |
| wheee | cool | cool  |
```

you want that as a result:

```
| first | info | d'oh  |  
| two   | info |  5    | <- highlighted
| three | info | hello |
```

---

My solution:

```
Sub UpdateSheet()
    Dim masterSheet As Excel.Worksheet, newSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim e, masterCell As Excel.Range, newCell As Excel.Range
    Dim columnOffset As Integer

    Const idColumn = 1 'column A has index 1
    Const newDataColumn = 5 'column E has index 5
    columnOffset = newDataColumn - idColumn 'offset between those columns is 4

    Set masterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New")

    'iterate over all cells of the first column in the used range of this worksheet
    For Each e In masterSheet.UsedRange.Columns(idColumn).Cells
        Set masterCell = e
        Set newCell = newSheet.Cells(masterCell.Row, idColumn)

        'if the cell on the master sheet is not empty and the values of both cells match
        If masterCell.Value <> Empty And masterCell.Value = newCell.Value Then
            'select cells in column "E"
            Set masterCell = masterCell.Offset(0, columnOffset)
            Set newCell = newCell.Offset(0, columnOffset)

            'copy values and paint row if values don't match
            If masterCell.Value <> newCell.Value Then
                masterCell.Value = newCell.Value
                masterCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        End If
    Next e

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi marcw, Sorry for late reply. Thanks for your inputs. I tried your solution and it is working fine if data of first column of master sheet matches with data of same row number of New sheet. But I need to find it any where in New sheet and update it in Master sheet.